# Finding the longest run of duplicate numbers in an ArrayList? (Beginner java)

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, iteration

This is my first time using stack overflow, so I'm so sorry if this is formatted incorrectly in any way. For a comp sci project, I have to do some different things to a 40-item Array List of random numbers.

The task I'm struggling with is this:

> **Count the longest run of the same number. A run continues only when consecutive numbers
> have the same value. The repeated number and the length of the run is then printed.** (Ex: Longest run is of number: 3, length is: 5.)

> If there is more than one run of maximum length, mark the last one. Print the array with the longest run marked in the following fashion:
> 1 1 1 6 5 4 6 3 2 3 2 (3 3 3 3 3) 1 5 6 3 4 4 4

I genuinely have no idea how to approach this problem. Even just some pseudocode could be helpful; I know that these should probably be 2 different 'for' loops, one that detects the run and the other that prints it. **I have some code from a friend who completed this using Arrays instead of ArrayLists:**

```
public String longestRun()
    {
        int maxRun=1;
        int currentLen = 1;
        int repeated = x[0];
        for (int i =1; i< 40-1; i++)
        {
            if (x[i] == x[i+1])
                currentLen++;
            else
            {
                if (currentLen >= maxRun)
                {
                    maxRun = currentLen;
                    repeated = x[i-1];
                    startRun = i-maxRun;
                    endRun = i-1;
                }
                currentLen = 1;

            }
        } 
        return "The longest run is " + maxRun + " and the repeated number is " + repeated ;
    }

public String printParenth()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<40; i++)
        {
            if(i != startRun+1 && i != endRun+1)
            System.out.print(x[i]);
             else if(i == startRun+1)
             System.out.print("(" + x[i]);
             else 
             System.out.print(x[i] + ")");
       
        }
         return "";
    }
```

I know how to create the ArrayList, convert to string & print, etc, it's just this one task that I don't understand. I assume this should be easier with an ArrayList, considering the increased number and utility of ArrayList methods. Thanks so much in advance, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Put your numbers in a list or an array.
- Set max to 1 (you will always have at least 1 number).
- initialize `count` to 1.
- initialize the variable `most` to the first number in the array
- also set the variable `last` to the first number in the array.
- Now iterate thru the list starting with the second number.
- If the current number **is** the same as last, increment `count`.
- then see if `count > max`.

  - if it is

    - set `max` = `count`.
    - set `most` = `last`
  - if it isn't

    - set `count` = 1
    - set `last` = current number
- continue in this fashion until all numbers have been checked.

At the end `most` will contain the number that was repeated and `max` will contain the length of the repetition.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is perfect. It took a couple tries to get the syntax right but I wrote something based on the guidelines you provided and it worked wonderfully! I really appreciate you taking the time to help me, thanks again! :)